# Why are inductively coupled RFID systems put in certain frequency bands when there are no EM waves used?

Tags: rfid, interference, coupling

LF - 125 kHz
HF - 13.56 MHz

Those frequencies refer to the magnetic field that is used to induce a voltage in the transponder. Can the magnetic fields actually interfere with EM waves in the vicinity?

Comment: I challenge you to create a 13.56MHz magnetic field without emitting EM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All electromagnetic stuff can be described using the four [Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations):

$$\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot \textbf D &= \rho_V\\
\nabla\cdot \textbf B &= 0\\
\nabla \times \textbf E &= -\frac{\partial \textbf B}{\partial t} \\
\nabla \times \textbf H &= \frac{\partial \textbf D}{\partial t} + \textbf J
\end{align}$$

The 3rd equation will tell you that a changing magnetic field will always be accompanied by an electric field. The 4th equation says that a moving electric field will always coexist with a magnetic field in free space. The two together mean radiation, and you can't pull them apart.

So there isn't really such a thing as "magnetic waves", only electromagnetic waves.

Comment: Corollary: there is no such thing as a "magnetic loop" or H-field antenna. All antennas respond to both E and H fields of an EM wave. Even if they're "shielded"...

Comment: What about loop antennas, with the wiring surrounded by a copper pipe, that Efield shield broken at one point, to avoid being a shorted turn? Hewlett Packard used this for 60KHz WWVB time-frequency standard receivers.

Comment: I am not an expert in loop antenna's, but [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70262/what-if-anything-makes-shielded-loop-antennas-so-great-at-rejecting-local-nois) seems to address your issue.